# boost shared_ptr interface/object

Tags: c++, boost, interface, shared-ptr

Suppose I have an API that has 2 methods that are to be used in conjunction with one another:

```
boost::shared_ptr<IAsset> getAsset( const std::string & id );
void update( const Asset & asset );
```

and I have a member variable of `boost::shared_ptr<Asset> asset` in another class. If I do:

```
asset = otherObject->getAsset("first_asset");

// do some stuff

otherObject->update( *asset );
```

I get errors of:

```
      \boost\include\boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp(378): error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'boost::shared_ptr<T>' to 'boost::shared_ptr<T>'
      with
      [
          T=IAsset
      ]
      and
      [
          T=Asset
      ]
      No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
      src\TestMethod.cpp(35) : see reference to function template instantiation 'boost::shared_ptr<T> &boost::shared_ptr<T>::operator =<IAsset>(boost::shared_ptr<IAsset> &&)' being compiled
      with
      [
          T=Asset
      ]
      \boost\include\boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp(378): error C2228: left of '.swap' must have class/struct/union
```

I should note here that the class definition for `Asset` does extend `IAsset` as in `class Asset : virtual public IAsset {...}`

Can someone tell me the correct way to do this as I have no access to the underlying API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your usage of inheritance is incorrect. If `update` requires an `Asset` then you either need to send it an `Asset` or a subclass thereof. `IAsset` is a super-class.

Answer (score 2):

That's a potentially unsafe conversion so you'll have to use a [dynamic pointer cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#dynamic_pointer_cast).

(Note that you can't use a `static_cast` from a virtual base class.)

Answer (score 1):

Because you're casting an `IAsset` to a `Asset` which requires a downcast.